# FileName from SMUGMUG

Tags: jquery, api, image

I'm trying to get smugmug filenames on individual images. Here's some code I found that gets the image..

the $.smugmug.images.getInfo line is where this needs to happen but I'm not sure how to implement it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
$.fn.smugmugCycle = function(options) {
var albumID = options.albumID;
var size = options.size || "Medium";

// Setup div
var div = this;

$.smugmug.login.anonymously(function() {
    $.smugmug.images.get({AlbumID: albumID, Heavy: 1}, function(images) {
        $.each(images.Images, function() {
            var url = this[size + "URL"];
            div.append("<img src=\"" +  url + "\" />");

            var img_id = this.id

              $.smugmug.images.getInfo({ImageID: img_id}, function(images) {
          alert(images.FileName);

      });

        });


        div.cycle(options);
     });
 });
```

};

Original code from https://github.com/jmaurer

... also, Apparently I can't make a new tag unless I'm more experienced on StackOverflow :(  *smugmug

Comment: It seems unlikely that smugmug would give the path to the images. It is likely that you will find a way to download the resource to your box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [images.getInfo](https://wiki.smugmug.net/display/API/show+1.3.0?method=smugmug.images.getInfo) to get the filename of an image. However you need to give it not only the ImageID but also the ImageKey.